# WPF: Validation.ErrorTemplate not displaying

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have a template for displaying a red border and an error message around controls. It works (tested on TextBoxes and ComboBoxes). But on two particular comboboxes they don't.
Well let's see what's different in the VM:

- since I have common validation implementation in my base class, no change there
- the same kind of asynchronously loaded data is displayed that works well with validation with just one panel over

so in short, *no difference in VM.*
The view is completely the same, the same style is applied, so in short *no difference* there either.

So I added `NotifyOnValidationError=True` to the `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` already there, and subscribed to `Validation.Error`... **And it fired**!!! Yet the template still doesn't show. ***I'm out of ideas, please suggest me things to check!***

EDIT: further research:

I've decompiled DataErrorValidationRule, and recompiled it as MyDataErrorValidationRule to match the original as close as possible. I removed `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`, and added my ValidationRule to debug. It returned `new ValidationResult(false, (object)str);` with str containing the correct error message twice - once for setting the property to null, and once for forcefully validating the entire object. ***Template still not showing.***

I've also checked Validation.GetErrorTemplate on the control (at the time of the first firing of Validation.Error) and it was *NOT NULL*, so it's not the `DynamicResource` that failed either.

EDIT: working example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionAnswers}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:QuestionAnswerModel}">
                        <StackPanel>
                                <!-- here is the combo box -->
                                <ComboBox Margin="8,4" Padding="8" MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource DefaultValidationErrorTemplate}" 
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Options.Source}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="ItemName" SelectedValuePath="ItemID"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Options.SelectedID, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}" />

                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
            </ItemsControl>
```

non-working example:

```
<ComboBox Margin="8,4" Padding="8" MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource DefaultValidationErrorTemplate}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Type.SelectedItem, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Validation.Error="ComboBox_Error"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Type.Source}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Localized"
                          >
```

They are from the *same xaml file*, the ItemsControl containing the working ComboBox is in the same Grid as the non-working ComboBox.

The only difference is whether SelectedItem or SelectedValue is bound, but that shouldn't have any bearings on the *validation*...

Comment: can you upload a working example for your problem?

Comment: can you check your settings on runtime with Snoop? the Validation.ErrorTemplate ValueSource should be Style in your case. i dont get your code working because i miss validation stuff and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem with the error template not displaying even though the event was firiing, and could never figure out why it only happened for some controls and not others.

The workaround I eventually found was to set the `ValidationStep` to `ConvertedProposedValue` on the `ValidationRule` for the binding:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="MyField">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <Validation:MyValidationRule ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" Message="Please enter a value." />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

That seemed to do the trick for me anyway!

EDIT: If you are using IDataErrorInfo, you could try (though I haven't personally tested it):

```
<Binding Path="MyField" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
  <Binding.ValidationRules>
    <DataErrorValidationRule ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" />
  </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

i.e. remove `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`, which is just a shortcut for including a single `<DataErrorValidationRule />`

Comment: could you link me something how you came up with this? I have never had to use manual ValidationRules before!!!

Comment: also the message should come from the data (attributes...), so how can I fill THAT?

Comment: I am subclassing System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule with my own class to suit my needs. If you are using IDataErrorInfo you could try the same thing (see edited post).

Comment: Typed: `<ComboBox.SelectedItem><Binding Path="Type.SelectedItem" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ><Binding.ValidationRules><DataErrorValidationRule ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>`, and the exception I got: `Validation rule 'System.Windows.Controls.DataErrorValidationRule' received unexpected value ''.  (This could be caused by assigning the wrong ValidationStep to the rule.)`

Comment: TDaver : I have the binding on SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem, works fine.  It's been a while but I think this doesn't work with SelectedItem (disclaimer: I could be thinking of something else here - like I said it's been a while).Like this: <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
<Binding
    Path="StatusId"
    UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <DataErrorValidationRule />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
</ComboBox.SelectedValue>

Comment: @MetalMikester: I have changed my binding to use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem (on the non-operational one), and it still no joy...

Answer (score 0):

i would check the following:

- check datacontext and binding for your combobox, if it works and IDataErrorInfo is called (i assume you do IDataErrorInfo validation)  - next step
- copy your validation template as a local resource to your ComboBox.Resources and check if it works

nevertheless it would be good if you post your validation template, your combobox xaml and your datacontext

Comment: first check definitely works, second one - I assume it does too, since the textbox RIGHT UNDER the not working combobox sees the template...

Comment: I've added my further research to the original post. still no luck :(